# Linux find specific names of PDF files in a external hard drive and copy them over into my destination flolder

Tags: linux, unix

I would like to state I am a newbie but I do understand the very basics thank you

I'm stuck here at work and I am trying to find files which are in a list in text file (they are PDF Files) and would like to search through a external hard drive copy them over on my local machine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy all .pdf files from `external-drive-path` (which is within a mounted filesystem) to your `local path` you could use find. The command below looks for all .pdf files from external-drive-path recursively and copies them to the local-path. The `-p` option of `cp` preserves modification times of the files.

```
find external-drive-path -type f -name \*.pdf -exec cp -p {} local-path +
```

Comment: sorry I don't know if I am explained properly I don't want to copy all pdf files I have a list of names of pdf files that I would like to copy across from the external hard drive which I am connected to locally to my local disk (there 97000 pdf files on the external hard drive but I need to copy 700)

Comment: It's still unclear. What is the list of pdf files - is it a text file?

Comment: yeah it is in text file it contains the actual name of the pdf file e.g. C012223, C021121, etc these are the name of the files I would like to copy across my Z:\ drive which is an external hard drive and I need the code to look through all subfolders